# Solving a problem using the definition of limit

Tags: limits, functions

How can I solve this using the definition of limit?

> Prove using the definition of limit that:
>   $$\lim_{x\to 1} (x²-4x)=-3$$

How can I approach this?

EDIT: OH my god! Thanks @adam!

Maybe you can also help me on out on that one:

> $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1}{x+2}=0$$

Comment: I would start by following the worked example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Worked_Example

Comment: Generally better to ask a separate question rather than wait for an answer to the first and then tack on another question.

Comment: Chech [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Then consider the quantity

$$|x^2-4x+3|=|x-3||x-1|$$

If we know that $|x-1|<\delta$, then we see this means

$$|x-3| = |x-1-2|$$
$$\le |x-1|+2$$
$$<2+\delta.$$

Hence we see

$$|x^2-4x+3|<\delta^2+2\delta$$

so if we do

$$(\delta+1)^2=\delta^2+2\delta+1=\epsilon+1$$

we see this gives a positive value

$$\delta=-1+\sqrt{1+\epsilon}.$$

we have the right result.

For the second one it's even easier. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Then we see that $$\left|{1\over x+2}\right|<\epsilon\iff |x+2|>{1\over\epsilon}$$

Since $x\to -\infty$, we can assume $x<0$ so that $|x+2|=|x|-2$, so choose $N={1\over\epsilon}+2$ and for $x< N$ we have the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! @adam! I edited the question, maybe you can help me out on this other one too, the minus infinity is dificulting the calculus.

Comment: @user136829 see my edited answer. Also, after this it's probably best to accept an answer and write a new question if you have more to do, it helps avoid constant edits.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to Adam's answer: First, ensure that $\delta<1$. So if $|x-1|<1$ then $-1<x-1<1$ so $-3<x-3<0$ and hence $|x-3|<3$.

Now use Adam's approach: $\left|x^2-4x-(-3)\right|=|x-1|\,|x-3|<3\delta$. So you can pick $\delta=\min(1,\epsilon/3)$.

That $\min$ trick is pretty common in limits and worth knowing.

Comment: Yeah, op:  this is worth mentioning since it's not always possible to solve for the optimal $\delta$ like I did there.

Answer (score 2):

**A more intuitive way to proceed:**
Let $\epsilon > 0$, we are looking for $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-1|\leq \delta$, then $|x^2-4x-(-3)|< \epsilon$. Note that

$$|x^2-4x+3| = |x-1-2||x-1| \leq (|x-1|+2)|x-1| <(\delta + 2)\delta,$$

so if $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3}\}$ then 
$$(\underbrace{\delta}_{\leq 1} + 2)\underbrace{\delta}_{\epsilon/3} \leq 3\frac{\epsilon}{3}= \epsilon.$$
And the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - 1| < \epsilon$, then $|x^2 - 4x -(-3)| < \epsilon$. The idea is to keep bounding $|x^2 - 4x -(-3)|$ until you get something that just is $\delta$ involving some constants whatsoever. Notice that $x-1$ is a factor of $x^2 - 4x + 3$, since the limit is true. I'd rather not do everything for you, since this kind of exercise is very important to get used to manipulating epsilons and deltas. But I answered a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598796/creating-a-question-that-use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f/854739#854739), giving the general strategy to deal with limits of polynomials. I believe that if you read it carefully, you can solve it yourself. If you have difficulties, please say, and I'll elaborate more on your specific problem.