# Have I proven this simple limit correctly? (trying a method that is new to me, using predicate calculus...but not yet "watertight")

Tags: limits, predicate-logic

$\lim \limits_{x \to 3} x^2 = 9$

Very simple limit, but I am trying a "new" (for me) method:

by definition:

$\left(\lim \limits_{x \to 3} x^2 = 9\right) \quad = \left(\lim \limits_{x \to 3^+} x^2 = 9\right) \wedge \left(\lim \limits_{x \to 3^-} x^2 = 9\right)$

For either conjunct, if I can show that there exists a function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(\epsilon) = \delta$, where $|x - 3| \leq \delta \implies |x^2 - 9| \leq \epsilon$, then I will have proven that the limit exists, as for any given $\epsilon$ I can produce a $\delta$ that satisfies the limit $definition.

---

$\lim \limits_{x \to 3^+} x^2 = 9$ case:

Since we are approaching 3 from the right, we have that $x > 3$.

$\quad (x > 3) \wedge (|x^2 - 9| \leq \epsilon)$
...can assume left conjunct and use definition of absolute value

$ = (x > 3) \wedge (x^2 - 9 \leq \epsilon)$
...algebra...

$ = (x > 3) \wedge (x^2 \leq \epsilon + 9)$
...law of specialization...

$ \implies x^2 \leq \epsilon + 9$ (**CONDITION 1**)

We also have:

$\quad x - 3 \leq \delta$
...algebra...

$= x^2 \leq \delta^2 + 6\delta + 9$ **(CONDITION 2)**

So now we have to conditions on $x^2$ that must be fulfilled when approaching $3$ from the right in order to satisfy the limit definitions. Recall that we want to find a function relating $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ when approaching $3$ from the right. Let us equate the right hand sides of these conditions, because then we will continue to satisfy condition 1 and 2, while coming up with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ relationship:

$\quad \epsilon + 9 = \delta^2 + 6\delta + 9$...algebra...

$= (0 = \delta^2 + 6\delta - \epsilon)$

I can now use the quadratic equation to find a meaningful relationship:

$g(\epsilon) = \delta = -3 + \sqrt{9 + \epsilon}$

---

$\lim \limits_{x \to 3^-} x^2 = 9$ case:

Since we are approaching 3 from the left, we have that $x < 3$. Additionally, I want to put in the condition that $x \geq 0$.

$\quad (x \geq 0) \wedge (x < 3) \wedge (-x^2 + 9 \leq \epsilon)$
...can assume left conjuncts and use definition of absolute value

$ = (x \geq 0) \wedge (x < 3) \wedge (x^2 + 9 \leq \epsilon)$
...algebra...

$ = (x \geq 0) \wedge  (x > 3) \wedge (x^2 \geq \epsilon - 9)$
...law of specialization...

$ \implies x^2 \geq \epsilon - 9$ (**CONDITION 1**)

We also have:

$\quad 3 - x \leq \delta$
...algebra...

$= x^2 \leq \delta^2 + 6x - 9$ **(CONDITION 2)**

So now we have to conditions on $x^2$ that must be fulfilled when approaching $3$ from the left in order to satisfy the limit definitions. Recall that we want to find a function relating $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ when approaching $3$ from the left. Let us equate the right hand sides of these conditions, because then we will continue to satisfy condition 1 and 2, while coming up with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ relationship:

$\quad \epsilon - 9 = \delta^2 + 6\delta - 9$...algebra...

$= (0 = \delta^2 + 6\delta - \epsilon)$

$g(\epsilon) = \delta = -3 + \sqrt{9 + \epsilon}$

---

So, does this method work?

Comment: It would be simpler to note that $x^2-9 = (x-3)(x+3)$, or, in other words, $x^2 = 9 + (x-3)(x+3)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure I understand :/

Comment: See Ivo's answer below.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209440/how-to-show-that-fx-x2-is-continuous-at-x-1/209492#209492).

Answer (score 3):

Looking quickly, it does seems to work, but.. my gosh, all that calculations must have been painful. There's an easier way. Given $\epsilon > 0$, I want $\delta > 0$ such that: $$0 < |x - 3| < \delta \implies |x^2 - 9| < \epsilon$$
First, see that once we've found the $\delta$ that does the job, any $\delta' < \delta$ will do too. So, we can suppose $\delta < 1$. I choose $1$ for simplicity, it could be another number. Fine. Since: $$|x| - |3| < |x - 3| < \delta < 1$$
we get $|x| < 4$, nice. So, we get: $$|x^2 - 9| = |x + 3||x-3| \leq (|x| + 3|)\delta < (4 + 3)\delta$$
by using the bound on $|x|$ and the triangle inequality. So, this way, $\delta = \min\{1, \epsilon/7\}$ does the job. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598796/creating-a-question-that-use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f/854739#854739) I gave the general method to dealing with $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs for polynomials, you might find it helpful.

Comment: The calculations weren't painful, rather, I seem to have a method which will almost always give me a straightforward way to prove limits (and not just for polynomials...), without having to guess too much. So, I am not looking for the "simpler", standard answer, as much as comments on my method.

Comment: I am also curious to know if it is okay to put a caveat on how large an epsilon the "other player" (in the delta-epsilon) game, is allowed to choose.

Comment: The other player can throw in *any* $\epsilon > 0$, and you'll have to manage to counter it with an appropriate $\delta$. Your solution should not put any restrictions on $\epsilon$. And, with $\delta = -3 + \sqrt{9 + \epsilon}$ this does not happen, it works well. But it would be cleaner to avoid square roots, summing constants, etc, IMO

Comment: If you can find a $\delta$ works for $\epsilon = \epsilon_0$, then the same value of $\delta$ will work for all $\epsilon > \epsilon_0$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 *facepalm* sometimes I think I am not cut out for math school...