# Symbolically find delta in terms of epsilon for proving that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(x^3+1)=1$

Tags: limits

I need proof the $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (x^3+1)=1$$  symbolically using $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.  I think I understand the basic concept of this, however I am having a difficult time when I get to $|x^3|<\epsilon$.

I'm just not sure what to do here.  I think I want to separate it into $|x^2||x|<\epsilon$, but I'm not sure exactly why.  I think I am having trouble understanding the reason for delta equaling the minimum of two things.

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: I tried rewriting so that abs((x^3)+1-1)<epsilon.  This gives me abs(x^3)<epsilon.  I'm just not sure what to do with x^3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you want to find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x| < \delta$, where $f(x) = x^3 + 1$. Let's start by playing with the $\epsilon$ section. We have $$|x^3 + 1 - 1| < \epsilon$$

We want to manipulate this so it looks like the $\delta$ part.  Fortunately, we're keen enough to notice that $1 - 1 = 0$, so we have $$|x^3| < \epsilon$$
In other words, we have $$|x^2||x| < \epsilon$$

That $|x^2|$ is what we have to worry about.  Let's, for a second, arbitrarily decide that we want $|x| < 1$. If that's the case, we have $|x^2| < |x| < 1$. Since $|x^2| < 1$, then $|x||x^2| < |x|$. Now simply let $\delta = \min (1, \epsilon)$. Why? If $\epsilon < 1$, then we can also use that.  The $1$ comes from the arbitrary decision to make sure $|x| < 1$, which is justified, because we're dealing with short distances.

So is this correct? Let's see:

Let $\delta = \min (1, \epsilon)$ (assume $\epsilon < 1$, and it'll still work out otherwise), then we have $$0 < |x| < \epsilon$$

But since $|x| < 1$ no matter what, then $|x^2| < 1$, and if this is the case, then $|x^2||x| < |x|$. So we have $$|x^2||x| = |x^3| = |x^3 + 1 - 1| = |f(x) - 1| < |x| < \epsilon$$

So $$|f(x) - 1| < \epsilon$$

Which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: I think this helps me understand it a little more, could you explain why it is important to separate x^3 into x^2 and x?

Comment: It's just a visual aid. Now that I think about it, it really isn't necessary.  What's important is that by limiting $x$ to be less than $1$, we know that $|x^2||x| < |x| < \epsilon$, so $|x^3| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the definition. Let $\epsilon > 0$. You want find $\delta > 0$, such that: $$|x - 0| < \delta \implies |(x^3 + 1) - 1| < \epsilon.$$
Put simply, what $\delta > 0$ should you pick, so that: $$|x| < \delta \implies |x^3| < \epsilon \ ?$$

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598796/creating-a-question-that-use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f/854739#854739) I gave the general strategy for dealing with limits involving polinomials only, using $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s, it might be instructive for you to read.