# Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate $f(x) = x^3+5x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> Using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit, evaluate $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$, where $f(x) = x^3+5x$.

**Attempt**

We can use the usual way of constructing the limit: $$\forall \epsilon, \exists \delta \quad 0 < |x-a| < \delta \quad \implies \quad |x^3+5x-(a^3+5a)| < \epsilon.$$ Then we get $|x-a||a^2+x(a+x)+5| < \epsilon$. I imaging now we are going to have to bound $\delta$ by say $\leq 1$ to get $|x-a| < 1$. Then I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the right way. We continue the attack using the triangle inequality: $$|a^2+x(a+x)+5||x-a| \leq (|a|^2+|x|(|a|+|x|)+5)|x-a|$$

If $\delta \leq 1$, then $|x-a| <1$ implies $|x| < 1+|a|$, so: $$(|a|^2+|x|(|a|+|x|)+5)|x-a| < (|a|^2+(1+|a|)(1+2|a|)+5)|x-a|$$You can simplify that coefficient, but the point is that $\delta < \min \left\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{(|a|^2+(1+|a|)(1+2|a|)+5)}\right\}$ will work. I wrote an answer about that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598796/creating-a-question-that-use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f/854739#854739), it might also help.

Comment: Technically we could choose any number to bound $\delta$ by, correct?

Comment: Yes. We pick $1$ for simplicity. If you bound $\delta$ by a constant greater than $1$, $\epsilon/{\rm constant}$ will be even smaller, though.

Comment: Slight typo. I think you mean $<$ in the second line.

Comment: The triangle inequality is with $\leq$, not $<$... the inequality becomes strict later, when we use $|x|<1+|a|$.

Comment: Sorry I meant fourth line.

Comment: Ah yes, then you're right. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: I just realized you can apply this same principle you applied here to pretty much any other question.

Comment: This line of thought is very useful.. this solves at least all questions about limits of polynomials. If you take a bit of caution with how you bound $\delta$, this works for all rational functions too. And we need not limit ourselves (pun intended) to polynomials of one variable.. I talk a bit about that in the answer I linked above

Comment: How did you get $ \frac{\epsilon}{(|a|^2+(1+|a|)(1+2|a|)+5)}$? Where did the epsilon come from?

Comment: I chose this because I wanted that expression in the denominator to cancel with what was multiplying $|x-a|$, leaving us with only $\epsilon$ in the end, which was what we wanted.