# I need to prove this limit by epsilon delta method

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

$\lim_{x\to a}{x^2=a^2}$

I get stuck midway, maybe i should give values to $\delta$?

Here is the process

$\left|x^2-a^2\right|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \left|x-a\right|\left|x+a\right|<\epsilon$  then i know that $\left|x-a\right|<\delta$  so $\delta\left|x+a\right|$<$\epsilon $  now i do not know what's next

Comment: Wait. Describe your entire process. It's not clear where you get stuck. How would you start with this question, for example?

Comment: [Read this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/854739/118056)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the inequality $|x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$:

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-a^2&<\varepsilon\\
x^2-a^2&>-\varepsilon
\end{cases}
$$

By solving both inequalities, you arrive at

$$
\begin{cases}
-\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}\\
x<-\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon}\;\vee\;x>\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon}
\end{cases}
$$

(without loss of generality for the second inequality).

Then the system is solved by

$$
-\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}<x<-\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon}
\;\vee\;
\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}.
$$

From the second part you can conlude that there exists a number $\delta$ such that, for all $x$, where $0<|x-a|<\delta$, you have that $|x^2-a^2|<\varepsilon$: just take $\delta=\min\{|\sqrt{a^2+\varepsilon}-a|,|a-\sqrt{a^2-\varepsilon}|\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint 1: $x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)$. You have control over $|x-a|$ directly with $\delta$. Try to bound $|x+a|$.

Hint 2: Taking $\delta<1$ can make things cleaner.

Comment: i dont know how to bound really, ive tried using 1/2 but im not familiar with the process

Comment: You know that $a-\delta<x<a+\delta$, then $2a-\delta<x+a<2a+\delta$...