# How do you prove this limit using the delta-epsilon definition?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

$f$ is a function with the domain of all real numbers, and let $a$, $L$ be elements of $\Bbb R$.

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a/5}f(5x)=L$

How would you do this without the limit law theorems?

Comment: Without the limit law theorems? Do you mean that we are to prove this by definition?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\epsilon > 0$. We want $\delta > 0$ such that $$0< |x - a/5| <\delta \implies |f(5x)-L| < \epsilon,$$right? How do we find the little bastard? He's hidden inside the limit that we already know that exists. For that fixed $\epsilon$, there is $\delta' > 0$ satisfying $$0 < |t-a|<\delta'\implies |f(t) - L|<\epsilon.$$I used $t$ instead of $x$ on purpose. With this, put $\delta \doteq \delta'/5>0$. Then: $$0< |x-a/5| < \delta \implies 0 < |5x-a|<5\delta=\delta' \implies |f(5x)-L|<\epsilon,$$as wanted. The moral of the history is that $5x$ plays the role of $t$ on the limit we already know that holds. My other answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598796/creating-a-question-that-use-the-epsilon-delta-definition-to-prove-that-f/854739#854739) might also be useful.

Comment: What does $δ≐δ′/5>0$  mean? I'm not really familiar with the symbol $≐$.

Comment: The dot means I am *defining* $\delta$ as $\delta'/5$. Perhaps you've seen the equivalent $\delta := \delta'/5$ before?

Comment: Make $t = 5x$ and look at the first implication in display, *which is true by hypothesis*.

Comment: Yea my mistake, should i re-enter the question for clarity for future readers?

Comment: No, I don't see any problem. The question seems clear as it can get.

Comment: One more thing, was changing the variable necessary or was that just to make the answer clearer? Like, could they have both been x or would they have to be x and x'?

Comment: Just to make it clearer for you. I could have used $x$ everywhere, since it would be a "dummy" variable. It boils down to logic.

Comment: I was looking over this question again and I was wondering why you were able to set x ('t') to 5x, I thought x was fixed to be all real numbers by definition?

Comment: Again: $x$ is a *dummy* variable, just as in  $$\sum_i a_i = \sum_j a_j$$ or $$\int_0^1f(u)\;{\rm d}u = \int_0^1f(v)\;{\rm d}v$$or $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{t\to a} f(t). $$

Comment: But t = 5x which =/= x right?